# Tesseract integration in Netsuite: Reading image content from File Cabinet

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Tesseraact in Netsuite
I want to read the content from image which are stored in netsuite File Cabinet. So i decided to use the Tesseract to read the content. How can we use this Tesseract in Netsuite?

I already tried to create a seperate library of tesseract code and use it in my client script but its showing an error that recognize not defined whereas I checked that recognize is used in the library.
I want to read the image content from file cabinet to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not the clearest but dissecting some parts you mentioned:

1. Adding library script into a SuiteScript.

This process is generally as follows:

- Add the file path in your "define" function
- Add a variable to represent this file in your callback function

Example:

```
define(['./ns_my_library_script'], function (myLibraryScript) {

    function doSomething() {
       var getVal = myLibraryScript.getMyFunction();
    }

}
```

2. Reading content from a file in filing cabinet

In any case, reading a file from NS is typically done by:

- Loading the file object (using N/file module)
- Using the "getContents()" function to return contents of file.

Example:

```
   var downloadedFile = file.load({
                id : file_name
            });

   var getFileContents = downloadedFile.getContents();
```

Not sure if this answers your question, but hope it helps.

Comment: But I have tried these all methods but these are not helpful File.load cant be used in Client Script If I use this in other type of script for reading the image content its not show the correct content and while using through the library. function Its throwing an error recognize undefinned.